# iOS app receive push notifications from firebase only when “test on device”

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, capacitor, ionic5

I have followed this guide to implement push notifications in my project with capacitor.

https://devdactic.com/push-notifications-ionic-capacitor/

Everything works perfect but i have a problem with IOS. It only works if i send a test message specifying the token of a device. But if I want to send a push to all registered devices by selecting the IOS platform, the push is never received. Any idea why this could happen? Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It finally fixed itself, it seems like it was firebase problem. The rest of my team received the push well. It started working for me a few days ago. Weird. I leave the answer here in case the same thing happens to someone.